# Could not resolve host error when trying to install the Homestead Vagrant Box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm having problems installing the Homestead Vagrant box following the guide on [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead).

I have the current latest version of Vagrant (2.2.6) and whenever I'm trying to add the laravel/homestead box to my Vagrant installation using `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` I get this error:

> An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
>   message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
>   again.
>
> Could not resolve host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com

Anyone have a clue on how to fix this and/or where the problem lies? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Looks like that URL is no good. Perhaps it is temporarily not working? I also have Vagrant 2.2.6, on Ubuntu.

Comment: No sooner than I posted my comment, now it's working for me./

Comment: @Kenny also works for me now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it works now as [Kenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810607/kenny) already said, for some reason now (a day later) files begin to download. Looks like it was a problem with S3 or something.